# Calculate Sum grouping by day

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *, 
       DATE(date) AS post_day 
FROM   notes 
WHERE  MONTH(date) = '08' 
       AND userid = '2' 
       AND YEAR(date) = '2016' 
ORDER  BY post_day DESC, 
          timestamp ASC
```

In this query I'm grouping my posts by day.

What I'm struggling with is calculating the total word count of all notes for each day.  There is a word count column which contains the word count for each post.  Is it possible to calculate this sum in the same query or does it need to be made separately?

By table columns:

```
NoteID    UserID    Date    Note    WordCount
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT date, SUM(wordCount) AS monthWordCount
    FROM Notes
    WHERE userID = 2
    AND MONTH(date) = '08'
    AND YEAR(date) = '2016'
    GROUP BY userID, date
```

Check out this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2ee41/1) using the above code.

If you want to return the notes as well you can do a subquery like below:

```
SELECT noteID, userID, date, note, wordCount, 
  (SELECT SUM(wordCount)
    FROM Notes
    WHERE userID = a.userID
    AND date = a.date
    GROUP BY userID) AS dayTotalWordCount
FROM Notes a
WHERE a.userID = 102
AND MONTH(date) = '08'
AND YEAR(date) = '2016'
```

Here's a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2ee41/8) using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `select *` with a `group by` query.  `select *` just doesn't make sense with aggregation . . . you need to apply aggregation functions.

I assume that you want something like this:

```
SELECT DATE(date) as post_day, SUM(WordCount)
FROM notes
WHERE MONTH(date)= '08' AND userid = '2' AND YEAR(date)= '2016'
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY post_day DESC, timestamp ASC
```

Comment: I'm looking to return the notes as well.  Not just the aggregation